# Why am I seeing extremely high L/D ratio of (e.g. L/D = 90) in my 2D airfoil analysis?

Tags: airfoil

Can anyone explain/justify why, using the 'Theory of Wing Sections' by ABBOTT the lift/drag ratios seem so high. For example, I'm doing an analysis of the NACA0012 airfoil and using their experimental data on pg462/463 at 8 degrees CL is roughly 0.9 and CD is roughly 0.001 giving a lift/drag ratio of 90. This seems incredibly high since as far as I'm aware lift/drag ratios go up to 70 to 75 practically from answers I've seen on here. My problem is that my CFD analysis also gives these high lift/drag ratios but I just didn't think it was possible.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: I would replace "possible" with "practical"

Comment: Could you be looking at lift/*parasite* drag only ratios? Induced drag depends on span only, so probably isn't included in 2-D section analysis.

Comment: @JanHudec yeah I suppose it could be that not all the drag is included since it's a 2D airfoil, are airfoil L/D g ratios generally larger then?

Comment: @Barnaby, the lift is approximated well by the 2-D analysis, so if any form of drag is not calculated, the L/D will obviously be higher than the final 3-D wing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that one figure looks at 2D flow around an isolated airfoil, where L/D ratios of up to 200 can be reached, while the other figure is for the 3D flow around a whole airplane, warts and all. The additional sources of drag which are absent in 2D flow around airfoils are:

- Induced drag. This will [double the total drag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/what-creates-most-drag-during-flight-fuselage-or-wings/52495#52495) right at the polar point of best L/D.
- Fuselage and tail drag. Of course isolated airfoils only have their own surface where friction drag occurs, but all the non-lifting parts on whole airplanes will bring D up without helping L.
- Lift loss at the tips. L/D for airfoils uses the pressure distribution and maybe a [drag rake](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33618/how-does-one-determine-the-freestream-and-ultimate-slipstream-velocities-to-esti/33620#33620) at the windtunnel center section, so no tip effects will tarnish the result, but the outer wings of airplanes will have [reduced lift relative to the local surface](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50301/do-wingtip-vortices-cause-a-decrease-in-the-lift-component-of-aerodynamic-force/50303#50303) and drag because of tip effects and to improve stall behavior.
- Trim drag: The tail can very well [add a downforce](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23427/why-are-aircraft-designed-so-that-the-wing-stalls-before-the-tail/23430#23430) to balance the lengthwise lift distribution with the location of the center of gravity. Now extra lift has to be produced by the wing, and [both, downforce at the tail and extra lift on the wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39460/does-the-wake-from-horizontal-stabilizers-merge-with-the-wing-wake/39491#39491), will produce more drag.